# Using .appendRow with formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I followed this tutorial and created a Telegram bot, which would send all messages to my spreadsheet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSXd_od4Lg

The point is that I need only one variable--text. So I modified the code a little bit:

```
  function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment " + text;
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([text]);
```

I do also have formulas for some ranges (say, B1:B21).

The **problem** is that the script would add my only entry to A22. Any ideas how to make it work properly, i.e., put 'text' in A1? Maybe there is a way to import that message ('text') as one string (cell), not a whole row?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of one cell you need to get that cell as a [`range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) (using [`sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)) & then use [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)).  e.g.

```
function setNewValueInLastRowOfColumnA(text){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var range = sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1); // getRange() can take 'A1' notation or (row, column) for a single cell
  range.setValue(text);
}
```

Now, if you want to set the value of B# to a formula that processes A#, you will have get another `range` for the formula cell & use [`range.setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) to set the formula. e.g.

```
var valueRange = sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
var formulaRange = sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2);
var formula = '=ROW() & " " & A' + (lastRow + 1); // which will make the value of B# '# your value'
valueRange.setValue("your value");
formulaRange.setFormula(formula);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first formula still adds a new row. I already have formulas in ranges and I want to keep them, but the script sees them (for instance, it sees the formula in D34) and thinks that this row is already filled and starts from the new, 35th, one. Any suggestions?

Comment: setValue is the key as mentioned by this answer.

Comment: @Ololeg, i'm not sure what you're asking now: your specification is unclear. Is it that you just want to *overwrite* the the value in A1 every time? If you *don't* want to add rows, then don't use `sheet.appendRow()` -- this will add a row --, rather use `range.setValue()` or `range.setValues()`